# How can I use selectors when getting data from a storage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I get use a selector when using `/data get` or `/execute store success ...`?
My storage looks like this:

```
{
  0: [
    {"Player1": 0}, 
    {"Player2": 1}
  ],

  1: [
    {"Player1": 1},
    {"Player2": 1}
  ]
}
```

I tried formatting it a little to make it easier to understand.

I want to know how can I make replace this: `/data get storage minecraft:waiting 0[].Player1`,
With something like this (this doesn't work!): `/data get storage minecraft:waiting 0[].{"selector": "@s"}`

Or this: `/execute store success storage minecraft:waiting 0[].Player1 int 1 run ...`
With this: `/execute store success storage minecraft:waiting 0[].{"selector": "@s"} int 1 run ...`

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. Have you considered storing the data in some other way, like a scoreboard?